# Can not activate CONDA environment using batch script

Tags: python, batch-file, anaconda, conda, command-prompt

I have a python script that I am trying to to run daily using Windows Task Scheduler. Based on some SO threads, I wrote a batch script and created the scheduler task. I am using Anaconda as virtual environment and version is 4.5.11. When I run the python script from "Anaconda Prompt" or "Windows CMD" it works just fine.

However, when I use the batch script to execute my python script from "Windows CMD" it fails to find my intended conda environment.

Here is my batch script,

```
set original_dir=%CD%
set conda_root_dir=C:\Anaconda3\Scripts
call %conda_root_dir%\activate.bat
cd C:\Anaconda3\Scripts
call activate yttv_crawler
python "C:\__ Work Station\Py_Projects\YT_TV_Crawler\index.py"
call deactivate
cd %original_dir%
exit /B 1
```

After running the batch script manually from CMD for test purposes, I am getting this-

```
C:\Users\aafaysal\Desktop>yt_tv_crawler.bat
C:\Users\aafaysal\Desktop>set original_dir=C:\Users\aafaysal\Desktop
C:\Users\aafaysal\Desktop>set venv_root_dir=C:\Anaconda3\envs\yttv_crawler
C:\Users\aafaysal\Desktop>set conda_root_dir=C:\Anaconda3\Scripts
C:\Users\aafaysal\Desktop>call C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
(base) C:\Users\aafaysal\Desktop>cd C:\Anaconda3\Scripts
(base) C:\Anaconda3\Scripts>call activate yttv_crawler
Could not find conda environment: yttv_crawler
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
(base) C:\Anaconda3\Scripts>python "C:\__ Work
Station\Py_Projects\YT_TV_Crawler\index.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\__ Work Station\Py_Projects\YT_TV_Crawler\index.py", line 1, in
<module> 
from data_access_layer import save_videos
File "C:\__ Work Station\Py_Projects\YT_TV_Crawler\data_access_layer.py",
line 1,
in <module> import pymysql
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'
(base) C:\Anaconda3\Scripts>call deactivate
C:\Anaconda3\Scripts>cd C:\Users\aafaysal\Desktop
C:\Users\aafaysal\Desktop>exit /B 1
```

But my conda environment does exists.

```
(base) C:\Users\aafaysal>conda --version
conda 4.5.11
(base) C:\Users\aafaysal>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Anaconda3
iqtools                  C:\Anaconda3\envs\iqtools
yttracker                C:\Anaconda3\envs\yttracker
yttv_crawler             C:\Anaconda3\envs\yttv_crawler
```

Here is the list of System Path Environment variables.

[image]

Please help me out.

NB: I know there are a lot of similar questions out there and I have nearly checked/tried everything and still have not been able to fix this.

Comment: @Mofi Screenshots are not of code rather the result of running the code or commands. In the 2nd screenshot you can see that I have run the `conda info --envs` and my intended conda environment exists

Comment: I have made the edits as you suggested. Thanks.